# How to add metadata to a lucene field

Tags: java, lucene

During indexing of documents, I need to store some metadata to fields.

For example:

1. I add the field `new Field("myField", "myValue", ...)` to the document
2. Now I need to store some kind of metadata (like the type of 'myValue' type) to that field.
3. This metadata should be indexed as well and stored associated to that field, so searching by the value or the metadata should result in the same set of documents.
4. Querying all values of `myField` will return a list of all indexed values supplemented with that metadata.

Is this possible at all? (May be I should better use some kind of database, but I have to use Lucene.)

Thanks in advance

**Concrete Example:**

I have SVG-documents (XML)

Any of that documents gets fields of type "component" with the values `"X35"`, `"Z89"` and many more

I need to store some metadata to `"X35"`, `"Z89"` and other:

```
 X35 => description="My X35 component", sizeX=10, sizeY=20<br>
 Z89 => description="Z89 part", usage_note="...."<br>
```

and so on

Comment: Are your needs not met by merely storing this information in another field?

Comment: The requirements are met storing another fields for the metadata (for example a field for the value type). What's not clear for me is the requirement [3]: the same result set will only be returned if you include allways a condition for the field value.

Comment: @femtoRgon Unfortunately not, because I have more than one field and any of those should have its individual meta-data

Comment: The abstract way in which this is phrased, I think, is making it very difficult to understand.  Perhaps you could provide a concrete example of what you are talking about?

Comment: @femtoRgon I have added an example to the original post, but I think it is not possible whith Lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some further research, I think, that it is not possible at all. I really should use a RDBMS ... ;)